# Combobox list open automatically after clic

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two comboboxes like:

[image: Comboboxes]

For some reason when I search something in first combobox and clic enter or select one item from the list my second combobox is selected automatically (blue highligthed) like this (I use event `combobox1_SelectionChangeCommitted` in first combobox):

[image: Issue]

So if I right clic in some area of my form that combobox open automatically. I'm trying to solve this using focus. Like

```
this.Focus();
```

or

```
somecontrol.Focus()
```

Events of first combobox:

```
private void combobox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboJobNumber.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
    GetSelectedValue(combobox1); // this set data in my second combobox
}

private void combobox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        GetSelectedValue(combobox1);
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        combobox2.DataSource = null;
        combobox2.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But it didn't work, what can I do to solve this? Regards

Comment: Could you show your on click event code?

Comment: Yes... I already upload my events @CabbageChampion

Comment: You have three ComboBox controls here: `combobox1`, `combobox2` and `cboJobNumber`. `GetSelectedValue()` behaviour is undefined. See whether you have also subscribed to the `SelectedIndexChange` event of any of those and, if that's the case, what's in there.